# Procedural maze/dungeon generation

Tags: algorithm, maze

Good day! Could you advice me a dungeon/maze generation algorithm to generate maps like this one?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKbGR.png]

Because most of the Maze generation algorithms making mazes for the whole map (or if I'll stop it in some step - it would be unfinished, or placed in neighbour cells). And most of the dungeon generation algorithms making sence to rooms, but I need only corridors.

The final maze must have only corridors (one tile wide) and deadends. Maybe with loops. It would be perfect if deadends count can be set.

Comment: Could you formulate all restrictions of generated maze? We need to know what is allowed and what is not allowed.

Comment: Is this map generated by a computer? We need several substantially different examples to be able to deduce what your maze generator should be doing.

Comment: I see three gray boxes lying over different 3x3 areas in your maze. What do these boxes represent?

Comment: Here comes the unavoidable question: What have *you* tried? What parts of *your* code do you have problem with?

Comment: And if you haven't done so yet, please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).